# What might cause edges of an FBX model to appear curved?

Tags: fbx

I'm developing an importer/exporter using the FBX SDK. One model I've been using for testing really has me scratching my head:

http://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/maya-tower-bridge/328242

When I look at the model with my own viewer, with some other 3rd party ones (like the [Clockstone one](http://fbx.clockstone.com/)), or based on the screenshots on TurboSquid, all the edges of the bridge look straight. But when I open it with Autodesk FBX Review, it looks all "bulgy":

[image: viewer screenshots]

The scene is composed entirely of meshes and I tried a variety of calls on the mesh parts to see if anything would be returned that didn't just look like default values. All to no avail.

Any perspective would be much appreciated!

Comment: I don't have time to write a whole answer on what it does and why it does that, but uncheck 'enable dynamic tessellation'.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! So it seems it pretty much comes down to a bug in FBX Review. In fact, I just tried updating to the latest version, and I don't even see the issue any more in v1.3.1.0. (Clearly I should have updated and tested before posting this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like I should add and accept an answer so people won't waste time reading this in an "unanswered question" list.

See the comments on the question. Essentially what I was seeing in FBX Review when looking at this file was actually due to a bug, which in v1.3.1.0 appears to be fixed.